# HTML options not showing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding some options through JavaScript to my HTML page but the options don't seem to be appearing. I do see them when I inspect them with F12 but they are not showing.

**Important Note**: Using bootstrap!

```
 <select class="browser-default" id='userSelect' name="userSelect">
     <option default>-</option>
 </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("userSelect");
for (var key in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = result[key].contactName;
        opt.value = result[key].id;
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

I did check if result has any value so that is not the problem (otherwise the options wouldn't appear). I think bootstrap is the problem here, because I read some things about it that it can be a problem in this case. Does anyone know how to solve this?

HTML Chrome Inspector:

[image: HTML Chrome Inspector]

Comment: It's probably not the problem, but you should use `.text`, not `.innerHTML`, for the text of the option.

Comment: Changed it, but not working.

Comment: Is it pure Bootstrap? Or you use some plugins like [`bootstrap-select`](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you use [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) plugin.

After every DOM manipulation to `select` you need to use [`refresh`](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) method of `selectpicker`.

```
for (var key in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = result[key].contactName;
        opt.value = result[key].id;
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
$('#userSelect').selectpicker('refresh');
```